# Display result of a variable in teradata stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, teradata

I need to print results of variables in Teradata stored procedures, but print does not work in teradata, should I use the below method or please suggest the proper one:
My code:

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE Name()
---some code goes here
BEGIN
      TRANSACTION;

      SET var1= var2+ 3;

      SET var3= var2;
      /* !!! PRINT var1*/
      /* !!! PRINT var3*/
end;
--some code here
```

I used the *out* in stored procedure declaration, suggest me another way to print the values of variable:

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE Name(out var1, out var3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as there's only a single line of values has to be returned you can utilize OUT variables.

For multiple lines you can use a Volatile Table where those lines are inserted and a final [DYNAMIC RESULT SET](https://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_16_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference%2FB035-1148-160K%2Flaf1472241407163.html%23) returns them as an answer set.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the value of a variable inside a stored procedure I assume you are asking in the context of debugging the store procedure. Teradata doesn't appear to have the debugging tricks that other databases provide, e.g. RAISE and NOTICE. One workaround is the create a log table with at least one column, `message VARCHAR(500)` and then insert your debugging messages into that table.